# SUM and GROUP BY diferent columns

Tags: mysql

I need to group the sum by different columns:

SUM1 group by Banco_Recarga

SUM2 group by BancoRetiro

```
SELECT Banco_Recarga, BancoRetiro, bancos_recargas.banco, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Tipo='1' AND (Status = '1' OR Status = '2') THEN '1' ELSE 0 END)  AS SUM1,
SUM(CASE WHEN Tipo='2' AND (Status = '1' OR Status = '2') THEN '1' ELSE 0 END)  AS SUM2
FROM transaccionesrr 
INNER JOIN bancos_recargas ON (transaccionesrr.Banco_Recarga = bancos_recargas.id)
WHERE Fecha_Recarga BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-10' GROUP BY Banco_Recarga ORDER BY SUM1;
```

I have been looking for hours but i can't find a solution

Comment: you most probably need 2 queries, and you cannot srt by a column that does not exist, where does `Recargas` come from? is it a column alias?

Comment: Sorry was my mistake, it is SUM1

Comment: also, without sample data to look at PLUS an expected result to look at, your needs are completely invisible to us.

Comment: I can do it with 2 queries but i got 2 different tables and i wanted to see if it was possible to get only 1 table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  SELECT
        CASE
           WHEN Tipo = '1' AND (Status = '1' OR Status = '2') THEN Banco_Recarga
           WHEN Tipo = '2' AND (Status = '1' OR Status = '2') THEN BancoRetiro
           ELSE 'Unexpected'
        END AS banco
      , SUM(CASE WHEN Tipo = '1' AND (Status = '1' OR Status = '2') THEN '1' ELSE 0 END) AS sum1
      , SUM(CASE WHEN Tipo = '2' AND (Status = '1' OR Status = '2') THEN '1' ELSE 0 END) AS sum2
  FROM transaccionesrr
  INNER JOIN bancos_recargas ON (transaccionesrr.Banco_Recarga = bancos_recargas.id)
  WHERE Fecha_Recarga BETWEEN '2017-11-01' AND '2017-11-10'
  GROUP BY
        CASE
           WHEN Tipo = '1' AND (Status = '1' OR Status = '2') THEN Banco_Recarga
           WHEN Tipo = '2' AND (Status = '1' OR Status = '2') THEN BancoRetiro
           ELSE 'Unexpected'
        END
  ORDER BY sum1, sum2
```

You may need to add conditions into the where clause.